# Angular 5, CanDeactivate hitting once with custom modal

Tags: angular, observable, angular-routing

Currently running angular 5
On one of our pages, we want a deactivate guard in place so that if a certain condition on the page is met (they start a test) and they attempt to navigate away without saving, they are presented with a custom modal (a p-dialog from primeNG container a custom dialog).

Here is the deactivate service that we have:

```
@Injectable()
export class DeactivateUnsavedChangesService implements 
CanDeactivate<any> {

   constructor() { }

   canDeactivate(
    component: any,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
   ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
     return component.confirm() ;
   }
}
```

Here is the parent components confirm method:

```
  confirm() {
    return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
      const subject = new Subject<boolean>();
      this.dcComponent.displayExitModal = true;
      this.dcComponent.subject = subject;

      return subject.asObservable();

    });
  }
```

I am accessing the child component (that which houses the modal itself) via a ViewChild

```
@ViewChild (DynamicClassroomComponent) dcComponent: DynamicClassroomComponent;
```

In the template, I am binding the 'subject' to an input field of the child component.  In that child component, I am binding that to the modal itself so it can do one of the following:

```
this.subject.next(true);
```

or

```
this.subject.next(false);
```

The issue is that the modal is showing once on a route change and never again and no matter what I select in the modal, it just closes and no route is taken.  I'm not 100% sure I'm doing this right so my approach may be totally incorrect.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating the `Tell-Don't-Ask` principle. Parent component should have no idea about the child component modal implementation. You should tell it to open the modal, and let it handle the implementation on its own.

> [Tell-Don't-Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) is a principle that helps people remember that object-orientation is about bundling data with the functions that operate on that data. It reminds us that rather than asking an object for data and acting on that data, we should instead tell an object what to do.

Also, you do not need to mix promises with observables. Just stick with a simple promise based solution.

**parent.component.ts**

```
confirm(): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.child.showModal(resolve, reject));
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
resolve: Function;
reject: Function;

showModal(resolve: Function, reject: Function) {
  this.show = true;
  this.resolve = resolve;
  this.reject = reject;
}

onDismiss() {
  this.reject();
  this.show = false;
}

onConfirm() {
  this.resolve();
  this.show = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution as it works perfectly and thank you again for pointing out the T-D-A principle.  I will be more cognizant of it in the future!

Comment: Glad I could help :)